# Maven Configuration issue, "Error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher in Windows 10"

Tags: maven

As i am trying to check Maven version after installing in my Windows 10 OS, i am getting above subjected error like Error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher. I have gone through few blogs as well threads about this issue but nothing i can find to resolve. Also i try to change my Environment variables as well path but i can't resolve the issue.
Here is my JAVA_HOME, Path, and M2_HOME details under Environment Variable.

JAVA_HOME - C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144
M2_HOME - C:\apache-maven-3.2.5\apache-maven\src
Path - %JAVA_HOME%\bin;%M2_HOME%\bin

[Error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXjYQ.png)

Please your help to resolve the situation.

Thanks,
Ranjith Lingala

Answer (score 3):

```
 C:\apache-maven-3.2.5\apache-maven\src
```

should be

```
 C:\apache-maven-3.2.5\apache-maven\bin
```

Comment: Are you sure you installed maven correctly? Path should be something like this `C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.5.2\bin` not inside `/src/bin`

Comment: What is the content of `src` and what is the content of `bin`? in `bin` you should find some Windows Command Script files.

Comment: Hi Brown, Thanks for answering.. Installing maven is just extracting the files and setting the path if i am not wrong. And we don't have bin directory inside the <Home>\apache-maven-3.5.2\ and we have bin directory here only in my case. C:\apache-maven-3.2.5\apache-maven\src\bin. Under src we have below content/folders bin, config, lib, main, site, and test these are all the folders, and under bin folder we have these files like mvn.bat, mvnDebug.bat, m2.conf, mvn, mvnDebug, and mvnyjp. Please let me know is these correct or not.

Comment: Hmm. How about this. You are using maven 3 now. So rename M2_HOME to **M3_HOME**

Comment: Hi Brown, Still i am getting initial error when i changed to M3_HOME. The error is "Error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher"

Comment: Hi Brown, Still i am getting initial error when i changed to M3_HOME. The error is "Error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher"

Comment: Try changing the path to  `C:\apache-maven-3.2.5\apache-maven` or  `C:\apache-maven-3.2.5\`

Comment: Did you download the binary zip?

Comment: I believe you downloaded the source zip. Try un installing your current Maven and download the binary zip.

Comment: Yes, It's right i have downloaded source zip, and faced that issue. After i remove and installed binary file it's working. Thanks Brown.

Comment: check as answered then